# Calculate annualized returns from quarterly observations

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate annualized quarterly returns from two returns series.

Given a vector r_a, it is fairly easy:

```
r_a <- c(.05, .02, .03, .08, .1, .04, .06, .08)
r_a <- t(t(r_a)) # I just need to transpose the vector
(prod(1+r_a)^(4/nrow(r_a)))-1 # This returns [1] 0.2491168
```

However, if I want a vector of several annualized returns based on multiple returns series in a matrix format, this approach does not work:

```
r_a <- c(.05, .02, .03, .08, .1, .04, .06, .08)
r_b <- c(.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .12)
mat_ab <- cbind(r_a, r_b)
```

How can I write code such that given a matrix with cols representing returns for different asset classes will output the quarterly annualized returns for each asset class in a vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
apply(mat_ab, 2, function(col_j){
col_j <- as.matrix(col_j)
(prod(1+col_j)^(4/nrow(col_j)))-1
})
#       r_a       r_b 
  0.2491168 0.4773500
```

Further, as you can see your code uses a matrix object:

```
r_a <- c(.05, .02, .03, .08, .1, .04, .06, .08)
r_a <- t(t(r_a))
class(r_a)
# [1] "matrix"
```

Answer (score 1):

Though there is an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266605/r-how-to-calculate-annualized-returns-from-quarterly-observations/57266695#57266695), I think the following can be of use. `nrow` is replaced by `NROW` so as to work both with quarterly returns *vectors* and *matrices*.

To see the difference:

```
nrow(1:10)
#NULL
NROW(1:10)
#[1] 10
```

And the function becomes

```
annualized <- function(x, MARGIN = 2){
  f <- function(y) (prod(1 + y)^(4/NROW(y))) - 1
  if(is.null(dim(x)))
    f(x)
  else
    apply(x, MARGIN = MARGIN, f)
}


r_a <- c(.05, .02, .03, .08, .1, .04, .06, .08)
r_b <- c(.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .12)
mat_ab <- cbind(r_a, r_b)


annualized(r_a)
#[1] 0.2491168

annualized(mat_ab)
#      r_a       r_b 
#0.2491168 0.4773500
```

Comment: Like that one. Did not know about `NROW`. Very useful!